# Limit object properties returned on Azure Tables JSON response

Tags: c#, class, azure-table-storage

Let's say I have an object which I want to get all properties when I'm inside my application, but I want to limit some of the properties sent back to users from my web API. My class is as follows:

```
public class NodeModel : TableEntity
{
    public NodeModel(string PK, string RK)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = PK;
        this.RowKey = RK;
    }

    public NodeModel() {}

    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }

}
```

So when I use `NodeModel` within my application I want access to:

```
object.PartitionKey
object.RowKey
object.Value1
object.Value2
```

When I return a query from Azure Tables I end up sending all properties including the `Timestamp` and `ETag` values. I'm not sure if this is a big deal or not but I'd like to know how to limit what's sent back. For example:

```
object.PartitionKey
object.RowKey
object.Value2
```

I have a method in which I deserialize inbound JSON payload directly into my `NodeModel`, then simply return it:

```
string data = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
NodeModel nodeData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NodeModel>(data);
return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, nodeData)
```

Aside from creating a new object of type `NodeModel`, then setting the properties manually for each one, is there a better way given the getter/setter or public/private keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an anonymous type with only the desired properties

```
string data = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
NodeModel nodeData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NodeModel>(data);
var responseData = new {
    nodeData.PartitionKey,
    nodeData.RowKey,
    nodeData.Value2
};
return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseData);
```

Or create a dedicated class to act as DTO

`NodeModel` should remain internal to the application and only expose what is needed over the wire.